How quickly does the chicken market move to equilibrium?
In Poland, people protest against the plan to build a chicken farm next to their homes and succeed in stopping it. Let’s say the farm would’ve produced 10,000 tonnes of chicken per year. How much less chicken will ever be produced in the world as the result of this?
I imagine that the chicken production will be increased somewhere else to fill the demand, but how quickly could I expect that to happen? I understand that it may be impossible to answer this, but is there any way to know at least very roughly what the answer might be? Could it be one week, 6 months, a year, 5 years?
I tried to look at elasticity of chicken and found some old data for Turkey and the U.S., but even if they applied to current-day Poland, I wouldn’t be sure if that would help to answer the question.

Maybe look into how long time it takes to build a chicken farm? This approach is used in electricity generation. Obviously, it is country-dependent etc. but for electricity generators, there is time to build estimates for different types of generators.

Perhaps it will never be built and people decide to eat some other type of meat or protein instead.
